# Upload local file to Telegram channel

Tags: python, upload, telegram, telegram-upload

I have a goal to do python script for checking new videos at yt channel then download and upload as audio to tg channel.
I've done first part with checking/downloading/converting (youtube_dl library) and don't see how to do upload part. (there are telegram-upload, python-telegram-bot, telethon libraries but i don't get which one and how I can apply for uploading files to channel)

```
# importing module
import youtube_dl
import urllib.request
import re

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/c/peterschiff/videos")

#all videos ids from yt page
video_ids = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html.read().decode())

  
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
    }]
}

#write all videos ids to local file 
txt_file = open('outfile.txt', 'r')
file_content = txt_file.read()
content_list = file_content.split()
txt_file.close()


x = video_ids
y = content_list

#get only new videos by comparing with local file
result = set(x) - set(y)

with open('outfile.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(result))

#download new videos and convert to audio
def dwl_vid():
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([zxt])
  

for item in result:
    video_one = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + item
    zxt = video_one.strip()
    dwl_vid()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-telegram-bot` is a library that provides a wrapper for the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots). `telethon` and `telegram-upload` instead use the [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/#tdlib-build-your-own-telegram) (also called MTProto), which controls *user* (and also Bot accounts).

If you want to use a bot to send files to the channel, you'll have to create a bot and make it an admin in that channel. Then you can use the api methods [`sendDocument`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument) or [`sendAudio`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendaudio) to send the file. For that you can either manually make requests to the bot api (e.g. via the `urllib` or other libraries like `requests` or `httpx`) or use a library like `python-telegram-bot`, `pyTelegramBotAPI`, `aiogram`, `botogram` etc that provide wrappers for the bot api. You can also use user-bot libraries like `telethon` or `pyrogram` for that, as they can be used for bots as well.

If you don't want to use a bot, you'll have to use a user-bot, i.e. the Telegram API such that the audio is sent by your personal account. For that, you can use libraries like `telethon`, `telegram-upload` or `pyrogram`.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to use Telethon, be sure to read the [First Steps](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/) of the documentation to get you started, and then use [`client.send_file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.uploads.UploadMethods.send_file):

```py
await client.send_file(chat, '/my/videos/video.mp4', caption="Test video")
```

Note that `telethon` uses `asyncio`, so be wary if you use `threading` elsewhere.